# Cron job in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

This should be pretty straight forward but I can't seem to get getting it working despite reading several tutorials via Google, Stackoverflow and the man page.

I created a cron to run every 1 min (for testing) and all it basically does is spit out the date.

```
crontab -l
* * * * * /var/test/cron-test.sh
```

The cron-test file is:

```
echo "$(date): cron job run" >> test.log
```

Waiting many minutes and I never see a test.log file.

I can call the "test.sh" manually and get it to output & append.

I'm wondering what I'm missing?  I'm also doing this as root.  I wonder if I'm miss-understanding something about root's location?  Is my path messed up because it's appending some kind of home directory to it?

Thanks!

---

UPDATE  -----------------

It does appear that I'm not following something with the directory path.  If I change directory to root's home directory:

```
# cd
```

I see my output file "test.log" with all the dates printed out every minute.

So, I will update my question to be, what am I miss-understanding about the /path?  Is there a term I need to use to have it start from the root directory?

Cheers!

UPDATE 2 -----------------

Ok, so I got what I was missing.

The script to setup crontab was working right.  It was finding the file relative to the root directory. ie:

```
* * * * * /var/test/cron-test.sh
```

But the "cron-test.sh" file was not set relative to the root directory.  Thus, when "root" ran the script, it dumped it back into "root's" home directory.  My thinking was that since the script was being run in "/var/test/" that the file would also be dumped in "/var/test/".

Instead, I need to set the location in the script file to dump it out correctly.

```
echo "$(date): cron job run" >> /var/test/test.log
```

And that works.

Comment: It's easy to set up a cron job in cPanel if you have it available.

Comment: where do you want that test.log file?  It's always better to completely write out the path in the script called by cron (eg `>> /root/test.log` or `>> /var/test/test.log`) to avoid this kind of surprises.

Comment: Thanks fvu, that was the problem I was not understanding.  I wrote it up as part of my "UPDATE 2".

Comment: 'But the "cron-test.sh" file was not set relative to the root directory.'  More precisely, the cron-test.sh process's *working directory* wasn't what you thought it was.  The working directory of a process executed from `cron` is the home directory of the account.  (And if you're running crontab commands as root, you might consider editing `/etc/crontab` rather than using the `crontab` command.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have not provided any path for test.log so it will be created in the current path(which is the home directory of the user by default).
You should update your script and provide the full path, e.g:

```
echo "$(date): cron job run" >> /var/log/test.log
```

Answer (score 2):

To restate the answer you gave yourself more explicitely: cronjobs are started in the home directory of the executing user, in your case root. That's why a relative file ended up in ~root.