# Cron Job not running on (Ubuntu Linux 10.04.1) server with Curl?

Tags: php, linux, magento, ubuntu

I'm trying to run a cleanup.php script on a Magento site hosted on Ubuntu Linux 10.04.1 the script command is:

```
curl -s -o /dev/null http://www.domain.com/cleanup.php?clean=log
```

and the script:

```
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/maintenance_script.
```

I have this script and command working on another server (1and1 shared)

I have had a look around the forums [Cron job in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7558393/cron-job-in-ubuntu) and tried different command versions but can't get it to run ? Curl is enabled on the server.

Can anybody help ? Many thanks[image]

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you don't have curl installed. :)

You may try to use `whereis curl` to let system check it for you.

Make sure you have installed [this package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy/amd64/curl/filelist) (or 32b alternative).

Or you can just use [wget](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wget) what is common linux CLI tool for such a tasks.

Comment: ; configuration for php CURL module
extension=curl.so

Comment: thanks , it has this entry in the curl.ini file ; configuration for php CURL module
extension=curl.so ? where would i use the wget command in the command ?

Comment: In cron:
`* * * * * wget -o /dev/null -O /dev/null 'http://www.domain.com/cleanup.php?clean=log'`

Comment: thanks this seems to work ? , i'm going to back up the db first and will run script again - i will post back with update thanks again

Comment: script seems to run for a while but does not work ? anymore ideas ? thanks

Comment: @Ledgemonkey what do you mean by *run for a while*, do you have memory limit and timelimit set correctly?

Comment: sorry bad explanation - the script runs to completion , no errors from the server , but the actual script does not work ? but i think that maybe a different question ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Am I the only one who spotted that the URL the cronjob is trying to call has "http://" repeated twice at the start?

Not the critical error, but still...